# Rpy2 not finding package despite finding other packages within the same library

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, package, rpy2

I'm using Rpy2 version 3.3.2 and despite being able to find other R packages such as 'spd', 'rugarch', 'Matrix', etc. I am not able to use 'rmgarch' despite all of these packages being in the path given by `.libPaths()`. When loading the packages using `utils.install_packages('rmgarch')`, I am told about the package and it's dependancies: `The downloaded source packages are in ‘/private/var/folders/...`. Yet when trying to use the packages

```
robjects.r('''
        
        library('quantmod')
        library('rmgarch')
        library('Bessel') #A dependancy
        f <- function(u) {
            l<-u
        }
        ''')
```

all are loaded except 'rmgarch' and it's dependency Bessel. The error given is: `RRuntimeError: Error in library("rmgarch") : there is no package called ‘rmgarch’`. I have tried specifying the location of the library `utils.install_packages('rmgarch', lib_loc=[path from .libPaths()])` but have not been successful. I don't know what else to try.
Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Are you certain that `.libPaths()` contains the package reported to be missing ? I have seen similar issue reports where it turned out that calling `R` and calling Python then R through `rpy2` lead to different R configurations (e.g., `R_LIBS`) or even different R installations on the system.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea. I think that may be the case here as well. The package is in .libPaths(). The strange thing, is that rpy2 recognizes other new packages which I load in, so I don't know why it can't access 'rmgarch'. It's very strange.